Prove that two non-parallel lines in a shared Euclidean plane will have exactly one unique intersection
Suppose we have the lines $f(x)=mx+b$ and $g(x)=nx+c$ where $n\neq m$. Then if $f(x)=g(x)$, we have:
$$mx+b=nx+c\rightarrow x=\frac{c-b}{m-n}$$
This proves that a solution does exist for when $m\neq n$. However, to prove uniqueness of the solution, we need to show that $f(x_0)=g(x_1)\rightarrow x_0=x_1$. I'll try proof by contradiction and assume $f(x_0)=g(x_1)$ but $x_0 \neq x_1$.
So we have
$$f(x_0)-g(x_1)=0$$
$$mx_0+b-nx_1-c=0$$
$$mx_0-nx_1=c-b$$
From this, I am having a hard time showing that it must be the case that $x_0=x_1$. Any hints on the direction to go is appreciated.

You've obtained an exact formula for the solution; all numbers it contains are unambiguously defined. What else is there to prove? To reformulate: you have proved (in particular) that if a solution exists, it is $\frac{c-b}{m-n}$. This is a number. It has a unique value.

I must be overthinking it, thank you!

"to prove uniqueness of the solution, we need to show that $f(x_0)=g(x_1)\rightarrow x_0=x_1$": no we don't (and we can't: this is false).

@AnneBauval for two linear functions of the form $a_ix+b_i$ where $a_i\neq 0$, then this statement is true, correct? It only doesn't hold when constant.

No, not correct. For instance for $1x+0$ and $2x+0$: $x_0=2x_1$ does not imply $x_0=x_1$. $f(x_0)=g(x_1)$ only means that your two points $(x_i,y_i)\in L_i$ are at the same height $y_0=y_1$.

I see, so for it to hold it for two functions like $f(x) = a \cdot x + b$ and $g(x) = c \cdot x + d$, then we would need to to have $ax_0-cx_1=d-b$ with $a=c$ and $d=b$

"However, to prove uniqueness of the solution, we need to show that f(x0)=g(x1)→x0=x1"  No. $(x,y)$ so that  $f(x)=g(y)$ is not a solution to the equation.   A solution to the equation is a value $x$ so that $f(x) = g(x)$.  To prove a solution is unique you would have to prove that if $f(x) =g(x)$ and $f(y)=g(y)$ then $x = y$.  That'd be easy to do (go ahead if you want) but you don't actually have to do that.  When you solved $f(x)=g(x)$ and got $\frac {c-b}{m-n}$ that was a specific value and the only possible value and that's enough to prove it is a unique solution.

@Lutterbach's previous comment. Indeed:
$$\alpha u+\beta v=\gamma\implies u=v$$  holds iff $\gamma=0$ and $\beta=-\alpha\ne0$. But this is off topic.

To beat a dead horse.... There are an infinite many $(x,y)$ so that $f(x) = g(y)$  we just need to have $mx+b = ny+c$ so $y=\frac {mx + b-c}n$.  $x$ can be any value and $y$ can be the result of $\frac {mx+b-c}n$ for any value.... To say $f(a)=g(b)$ is to say... At $x=a$ we look at the value $f(a)$.  The we draw a horizontal line test, there is another value $b$ where $g(b)$ will have the same value.  That's ... not relevant really.

Guys in the comments, you all are beating the wrong dead horse. $g(x_{1})=f(x_{2}) \Rightarrow x_{1} = x_{2}$ is simply not the correct condition for uniqueness. The correct condition would be $\exists ! x : mx+b = nx +c$, which is exactly what the OP has proved (then proceeding to misinterpret the uniqueness condition and overcomplicate the problem)
